# Wrong username being returned, missing single quote

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
Dim path As String
Dim user As String
user = CreateObject("WScript.Network").username
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Roaming\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B16") & ".log"
```

This works for everyone except one person.

The VBA code above returns the following path:
`C:\Users\ABcdeF\AppData\Roaming\`

`%appdata%` returns the following path:
`C:\Users\A'BcdeF\AppData\Roaming`

Note the missing single quote in the first example. I tried the three following methods of obtaining the username without success:

1. `Environ("username")`
2. `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")`
3. `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`

In my opinion, the username is wrong and needs to be changed by my organization?

Comment: Why not just use `environ("appdata")`?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld post an answer and I'll accept it. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your issue is obtaining the path to the `...Roaming` folder for the `user`.

If that is the case, I suggest using:  `environ("appdata")`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Application.UserName` for my work.

Or try too, `replace(Environ("username"), "'", "")` this remove this (') only, work around the problem.

Comment: `Application.UserName` is a different thing.

Comment: BigBen, agree with you, I know for that reason, try.